# understanding a simple recursion method

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn about recursion and how it can be used to solve problems.

The question is, what does the method call recur(4) display?

```
public static void recur (int n)
{
  if(n==1)
  {
    System.out.print(n);
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.print(n);
    recur(n - 1);
  }
}
```

since n does not equal 1, it resorts to recur(n - 1) but this is where I am confused as to what happens here? Would the output be something along the lines of 3,2,1,0?

Comment: can't you just call `recur(4)` and see for yourself?

Comment: Yep, as @R.J states, and even better, step through the code with your debugger as it runs.

Comment: Why don't you run the program and check the output that ways? On first glance, the output should be 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 1):

It will print: `4321`.

If you call `recur(4)`, then `n == 4` when you start. It is not 1, so it goes to the else block, where it prints a 4, and then calls `recur(3)` (4-1 = 3). After that, it still isn't 1, so once again you go to the else block. This time `n == 3`, so 3 is printed out. Then `recur(2)` is called, which once again goes to the else block, printing out 2 and calling recur(1). n is equal to 1 now, so the if block is executed, which simply prints 1.

Note that you get `4321` as you have a `System.out.print()` statement, with no spaces. A `println()` would put it on a new line everytime, and you'd get:

```
4
3
2
1
```

But with a `print()` statement and no spacing, you'll simply get `4321`

Comment: Thanks, wanted to know exactly this instead of just "plugging it in"

Comment: @aiuna You're welcome. However, it would be much clearer to you if you used breakpoints and saw the values change as the execution happened.